# Как заблокировать элемент Combobox?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qcombobox

```
self.rang.setItemText(0, _translate("regform", "Выберите должность"))
```

Есть элемент, который надо заблокировать, а именно "Выберите должность". Надо сделать так, что его нельзя выбрать, но он будет светиться.

Comment: А что значит заблокировать?

Comment: Ну сделать так, что его нельзя выбрать, но он будет светиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox

app = QApplication([])

combo_box = QComboBox()

for i in range(10):
    combo_box.addItem("item_" + str(i + 1))

# QStandardItemModel, метод model.item возвращает объекты QStandardItem
model = combo_box.model()

# Указываем какие элементы сделать невыбираемыми
model.item(0).setEnabled(False)
model.item(2).setEnabled(False)
model.item(4).setEnabled(False)

combo_box.setCurrentIndex(-1)

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(combo_box)

mw = QWidget()
mw.setLayout(layout)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что self.rang.setItemText(0, _translate("regform", "Выберите должность")) это в самом макете, не могли бы вы вот эту строчку изменить?

Comment: @МаксимХалин, а в у вас чем проблема?

Comment: в вк сможете ответить?

Comment: @МаксимХалин, нет, тут. Да и не понимаю в чем у вас проблема. после той строки из вопроса, просто вызываете: `self.rang.item(0).setEnabled(False)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'QComboBox' object has no attribute 'item':

Comment: Если делать такую строчку 'self.rang.itemText(0).setEnabled(False)' то ошибка AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setEnabled':

Comment: Тьфу, точно: `self.rang.model().item(0).setEnabled(False)`

Comment: `self.rang.setItemText(3, _translate("regform", "Бригадир"))` вот эта строчка не отображается

Comment: `self.rang.setItemText(0, _translate("regform", "Выберите должность"))
        self.rang.model().item(0).setEnabled(False)
        self.rang.setItemText(1, _translate("regform", "Диспетчер"))
        self.rang.setItemText(2, _translate("regform", "Рабочий"))
        self.rang.setItemText(3, _translate("regform", "Бригадир"))` То есть получается вот такой комбо бокс, но Бригадир не высвечивается

Comment: В смысле, тот элемент заблокирован?

Comment: Заблокирован тот элемент, но почему то третий элемент не высвечивается

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под не высвечивается? Вы мой код запускали, он у вас работает?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/h2SmSqh.png Вот, не работает пункт "Бригадир"

Comment: У вас его нет в комбобоксе. Эта проблема к этому вопросу не относится, т.к. она стопудов была до нее. self.rang.setItemText не добавляет элемент если его нет, поэтому если у вас при `self.rang.setItemText(3, ` нет 4-х элементов в комбобоксе, то и не появится. Используйте `self.rang.addItem` чтобы добавлять их

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь.

Comment: @МаксимХалин, удачи :)